# Generate random data value

Tags: r, random-variable

I am being asked to generate random data values for Gam(2,0.25) using rexp(n,0.5) where n is number of values in R. I tried using the method of generating random numbers from uniform distribution but it gets really messy.

If you could explain how I would do this, that would be great. To reiterate must use rexp(n,0.5), can not use rgamma to directly solve.

Comment: What does linear distribution look like?

Comment: Hint: the sum of independent exponential variables is gamma.

Comment: @a_statistician I think linear means uniform here.

Comment: Sorry, I meant uniform. Thanks for the hint, I got it.

Comment: Maybe you could explain what you got in an answer

Comment: The statement of the question in the duplicate describes the approach sketched in these comments.  The answer describes another method.